# buscando un codigo c# para unity

Tags: c#

hola alguien me podría decir un script parecido a de este gif?(pero que se pueda usar las flechas direccionales o mouse)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No. Muestra lo que has intentado y qué problemas específicos has tenido. [es.so] no es un servicio de código. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: no me fue tan util tu respuesta pero gracias